# Kaa ESP8266 Compiler error

Tags: c, cmake, header-files, esp8266, kaa

I have built the ESP8266 SDK according to [this document](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/C/SDK-ESP8266/)

But the compile report shows the error below.

```
[ 35%] Building C object kaa/CMakeFiles/extension_notification.dir/src/extensions/notification/kaa_notification_manager.c.obj
In file included from /home/gian/Scrivania/espdemo/kaa/src/extensions/notification/kaa_notification_manager.c:33:0:
/home/gian/Scrivania/espdemo/kaa/src/kaa/platform-impl/esp8266/platform/sock.h:20:31: fatal error: lwip/lwip/sockets.h: No such file or directory
 #include <lwip/lwip/sockets.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
kaa/CMakeFiles/extension_notification.dir/build.make:62: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "kaa/CMakeFiles/extension_notification.dir/src/extensions/notification/kaa_notification_manager.c.obj" non riuscito
make[2]: *** [kaa/CMakeFiles/extension_notification.dir/src/extensions/notification/kaa_notification_manager.c.obj] Errore 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:449: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "kaa/CMakeFiles/extension_notification.dir/all" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [kaa/CMakeFiles/extension_notification.dir/all] Errore 2
Makefile:127: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "all" non riuscito
make: *** [all] Errore 2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for adding more information to the question. Please learn to do markdown, for improving readability. Check the edit I made, the one which you ignored with your edit.

Comment: No need to place the same message twice, this is not additional information. Rolled back and added "language: none" for even better readability.

Comment: compiler cant fine sockets.h file   in lwip/lwip/sockets.h address. this is a common error. first try to solve this.

Comment: @EsmaeelE I writed exactly the CMakeLists.txt of the documentation.

Comment: @Gian please express compilation command chains

Comment: @EsmaeelE     You can see it in documentation on the section **Build application**

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a uncorrect name in the file esp8266.cmake. In line 49 I changed 
set(ESP8266_SDK_PATH /opt/Espressif/**ESP8266_SDK**) with set(ESP8266_SDK_PATH /opt/Espressif/**esp-rtos-sdk**)